# How do I link css to html while both files are in the same package in a project in Eclipse? (html loads from custom made http server)

Tags: html, css, eclipse

To everyone willing to listen to my probably minor problem,

I have been having a problem making my css show up in my html after loading it. Once I start my http server, the html loads just fine, unlike the css which is not shown at all. This is probably the part I'm having issues with:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\htmlFajlovi\style.css">
```

At first I tried having only style.css under href, but that didn't seem to work. Then I tried adding all the possible paths to the file that I could think of (the following picture is the picture of the project tree):[Tree of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlfUL.png)

the paths I've tried were "src/htmlFajlovi/style.css", "src\htmlFajlovi\style.css", "\htmLFajlovi\style.css". "/htmlFajlovi/style.css" and the ordinary "style.css". Nothing worked. I'm really in a bind here. Thank you in advance for your help and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path is wrong:
Give link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/htmlFajlovi/style.css">
```

or

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

add forward / between file address.

Let me know if its not working...?

Comment: Use the second one since the css files is inside the same folder where html file exist...

Comment: Thank you, I've used the second one and it worked after I modified my http server response class, I guess it wasn't an html problem at all xD Thank you for taking your time. :3

Comment: Please vote up if my answer help you... since it will be a reward for us and provide us feedback to help others...Thanks..:)